# What's the meaning of "Unsolicited ARP mode"?

Tags: linux

As I know, arping requests another mac informaion on which another HOST of IP address is held.

However, I can't understand [Unsolicited ARP mode] with -U option.

```
# arping -i
arping: invalid option -- 'i'
Usage: arping [-fqbDUAV] [-c count] [-w timeout] [-I device] [-s source] destination
  -f : quit on first reply
  -q : be quiet
  -b : keep broadcasting, don't go unicast
  -D : duplicate address detection mode
  -U : Unsolicited ARP mode, update your neighbours
  -A : ARP answer mode, update your neighbours
  -V : print version and exit
  -c count : how many packets to send
  -w timeout : how long to wait for a reply
  -I device : which ethernet device to use (eth0)
  -s source : source ip address
  destination : ask for what ip address

# arping 10.10.10.50                                            
ARPING 10.10.10.50 from 10.10.10.32 bond0                  
Unicast reply from 10.10.10.50 [XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX]  0.706ms
Unicast reply from 10.10.10.50 [XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX]  0.692ms
......

# arping -U 10.10.10.50
bind: Cannot assign requested address
```

I'm working on CentOS 6.2. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In a normal scenario, if machine A generates an ARP request, then it will have its own Ethernet (MAC) address and the IP address of machine B (the machine whose MAC address machine A wants to discover). This ARP packet will be broadcast on the Ethernet network and a unicast reply will be sent from machine B to machine A, containing machine B's MAC address. Once machine A receives reply from machine B it updates its ARP cache; in other words, it associates machine B's IP address with its MAC address.

In Unsolicited ARP, the packet generated by machine A will have its own Ethernet address (just like the normal scenario) but instead of adding machine B's IP address, the packet will have machine A's IP address. Such an ARP packet is used to update the neighbor's ARP cache. That is, for example, if the IP address of machine A changes, then it can generate such an ARP packet, and once it is received by all other machines in the network, they can update their local caches with machine A's new IP address.